# Jackson 1.9 and stateless configuration objects (fluent interface)

Tags: jackson

I used to do this (in setupContext in a subclass of SimpleModule):

```
DeserializationConfig dc = context.getDeserializationConfig();
dc.disable(Feature.CAN_OVERRIDE_ACCESS_MODIFIERS);
dc.disable(Feature.READ_ENUMS_USING_TO_STRING);
dc.disable(Feature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);
```

But get deprecation warnings in 1.9, so I try :

```
DeserializationConfig dc = context.getDeserializationConfig();
dc.without(Feature.CAN_OVERRIDE_ACCESS_MODIFIERS)
  .without(Feature.READ_ENUMS_USING_TO_STRING)
  .without(Feature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);
```

but this seems to have no effect, since after these calls

```
dc = context.getDeserializationConfig();
System.out.println(dc.isEnabled(Feature.CAN_OVERRIDE_ACCESS_MODIFIERS));
System.out.println(dc.isEnabled(Feature.READ_ENUMS_USING_TO_STRING));
System.out.println(dc.isEnabled(Feature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES));
```

prints

```
true
false
true
```

which seem to be the default values. What am I missing here ?

Comment: Guess I must live with the deprecated methods ? http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JACKSON-686

Answer (score 1):

These methods create new instances, so you MUST assign them. They have been added to get to bit more functional style, trying to make most objects immutable, which in turn helps a lot with concurrency (basically can share instances without synhcronization).
Naming convention tries to make this clear: set - methods change state, withXxx() methods are "fluent factories".

That some frameworks use fluent methods purely for chaining, but in most cases these are for Builder objects (mutable), and then resulting immmutable objects have no methods for changing state; but there may be methods to create new Builders.
Jackson uses withXxx() methods in most cases, without builders (there are some cases where full builders are used, but these are minority).

As you correctly note, issue 686 is related to specific case of changing features via Module interface. This is an unfortunate side effect of other changes and needs to be addresses for the next release. But until you either need to change features directly via ObjectMapper (setDeserializationConfig(...), or configure(...), or use deprecated methods if you must use module interface.